# Limit string length with RegEx

Tags: php, regex

I wrote this `regex` for checking the input number from my form:

```
if (!preg_match("/^0\d{10}+|^9\d{9}+/",$_POST['number'])){
   echo "Error";
}else{
   echo "Ok";
}
```

this code will check the minimum length but if length is more than 10 or 9 characters, this regex cannot work !

What should I do ? should I check with `strlen` after Regex or I can limit the maximum length ?

**UPDATE:**

the string length should be exactly 10 characters if start with 0 and should be exactly 9 characters if start with 9, and should return false on another ways (more or less length, start with different numbers and ...)

Comment: @MarcB Thanks,I cannot understand your mean, I updated my question too

Comment: Why in the seven hells would you validate an integer as a string with a length check in a regex? `intval($_POST['number']) >= 100000000 && intval($_POST['number']) < 1000000000`

Comment: @Sammitch: just because it's digits doesn't mean it's an integer. e.g. `00000000001` != `1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly you just want to anchor the string at the end using `$`. Also can drop the `+` after the numeric quantifier:

```
^(?:0\d{9}|9\d{8})$
```

[See test at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/vG8sQ2/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
'/^(0\d{9}|9\d{8})$/'
```

This will allow string length exactly 10 characters if it starts with 0 and should be exactly 9 characters if input starts with 9.